# jQuery datepicker get current date from server-side

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can i get current date from server-side (such as new Date from server date time not from client'computer date), when i use jQuery datepicker?

Do i need get time from server and pass it to the js code? How can i do it. i am using classic asp

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the date you can simply add the date to a javascript variable when you are creating the page. Something like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var date = <%=date()%>;
</script>
```

Just use that date var to set the date for the datepicker.

Comment: This is client-side, and may not match the server, for example...roll back your clock, or live in across the international dateline.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little approach.

Step 1: Create an hidden input field anywhere on the page..

```
<input type="hidden" name="mydate" value=""/>
```

Step 2: Insert the php date code in the value attribute..

```
<?php echo date('D, d, Y') ?>
```

Step 3: now use jquery to get the value of this field and assign it to a variable..

finished

Answer (score 0):

Why can you not just set the date inline as the input value? For example...

```
<input type="text" name="mydate" value="<%=FormatDateTime(Now,2)%>"/>
```